# Split string in vb.net based on a word (as in PHP explode)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I want to split a string in vb.net based on a word. just like we do in php

```
explode("Sender: ", $str);
```

When I do the following in vb.net (VS 2010)

```
Dim splitContent = readFileContent.Split("Sender: ")
```

it is not giving proper results, any help please.

when the file content is

```
Sender: hello worldS1
Sender: hello world2
```

The output i get is : `"","ender :hello world","1","ender hello world2",`

Comment: Please be clearer - what are the 'not proper results' and how do they compare with what you expect?

Comment: What is the proper result?

Comment: edited the question (added output)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `String.Split` in that way. You are passing a string, that compiles with `Option Strict` set to `Off`(also don't do that). But what happens is that actually `String.Split` will only take the first character from the string as delimiter.

Instead use a `String()` with the [correct overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Dim splitContent = readFileContent.Split({"Sender: "}, StringSplitOptions.None)
```

Comment: Thank you @Tim Schmelter you  saved my day!